# Adjust System.Web.Optimization bundling to not minify files that can't be minified

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, optimization, bundle

In the past year I do a lot of use with System.Web.Optimization Bundling & Minificaiton. Though I'm not yet an expert, i pretty much know most of it's goods and bads.

One of the problems i have is regarding the **CSS bundling**: while you attempt to minify multiple files into one bundle, if one file has some content that can't be minified, then the entire bundle remains unminified with a comment of on top :

***/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.***

In such cases though 90% of the minify worked, a single file could affect the decision wheter or not the bundle is minified.

This is an exmaple
(looks like the @keyframes, @import, @-moz-.. and such tokens, but not just these ones cause a run-time error on minification)

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(518,32): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(518,32): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(518,32): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(518,32): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
(569,32): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(569,32): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(569,32): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(569,32): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
(1209,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@CHARSET'
(1209,10): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '"UTF-8"'
(1209,17): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ';'
(1445,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@-webkit-keyframes'
(1446,3): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '0%'
(1449,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@-moz-keyframes'
(1450,3): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '0%'
(1457,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@-ms-keyframes'
(1458,3): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '0%'
(1461,1): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@keyframes'
(1462,3): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '0%'
(1521,2): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@-webkit-keyframes'
(1522,8): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found '{'
(1530,2): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found '@keyframes'
(1531,8): run-time error CSS1035: Expected colon, found '{'
....
 */
```

I know there are something called [Transformers](https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer) (not sure if it's the only way), but i really can't find any easy-to-understand resource with relevant examples.
What I'd like to achieve is that if a file can't be minified, simply keep it unminified but **inside the same bundle definition**.

for example if i have file1.css, file2.css, file3.css, and only file2.css can't be minified i would like to see the next result in my bundle:

```
<content of file1.css minified>
<content of file2.css unminified>
<content of file3.css minified>
```

hoping anyone could help

Comment: Anyone knows this issue?